# How to use memoization to generate non-repeating random numbers?

Tags: javascript, recursion, caching, memoization

I'd like to use a self-written function to generate non-repeating random keys for HTML elements.

The issue is that the cache gets lost at each function call.

This is my code so far:

```js
function generateRandomKey(cache = []) {
  const newRandomKey = Number(Math.random().toFixed(2));
  if (cache.includes(newRandomKey)) return generateRandomKey(cache);
  cache.push(newRandomKey);
  return newRandomKey;
}
```

I could declare `cache` out of the function scope, which would be available globally as I would like the cache to be, but I'm afraid this would be bad practice.

I've thought of using memoization, something like this:

```js
const memoizedRandomKey = (cache = []) => {
  return (generateRandomKey) => {
    const key = generateRandomKey();
    if (cache.includes(key) {
      return memoizedRandomKey(cache)
    }
    else {
      cache.push(key)
      return key
    }
  }
}
```

However the cache also keeps getting overwritten.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or if memoization would even be useful in this case.

Which approach would you recommend? Where is the flaw in my logical thinking?

Thank you.

Comment: It is bad practice to use global variables *for non-global data*.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thank you. What if I declared individual cache arrays in all local components which need different IDs? That would be out of the function scope, but not globally available, & passed as a function argument.

Comment: Good question @ElMoscaviador Be aware that as the size of your cache increases (i.e. as keys are 'used') your algorithm will take longer to find an unused combination; see the second interactive example here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

Practically speaking if the pool of possible keys is big enough vs the number of keys you need it might not become an issue.

Comment: Do you know, that `Number(Math.random().toFixed(2));` can create a number like `0.939999999999999947`? In this example, toFixed() returns a text `"0.94"`. If converting to a number, the nearest possible number is returned (0.94 is not possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**don't use random keys**

Each time you reach into the same random space, there's a potential that you receive a non-unique value. To check whether you have already seen a particular value, you would need some sort of cache.

**don't use a cache**

As the cache fills up, it's harder and harder to find a unique value that hasn't be used.

**don't use splice**

Using `.splice` resizes the array each time a random is generated.   [This is a very costly operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65638217/633183).

**keep it simple**

This sequential ID generator guarantees the IDs will be unique, without any need for collision detection, caching, preallocation, or other expensive computations. For use with generated HTML elements, this is sufficient -

```js
function createGenerator(init = 0) {
  return () => (init++).toString(16).padStart(2, "0")
}

const foo = createGenerator(1000)
const bar = createGenerator()

console.log(foo(), foo()) // 3e8 3e9
console.log(bar(), bar()) // 00 01

console.log(foo(), foo()) // 3ea 3eb
console.log(bar(), bar()) // 02 03
```

**preallocated, random order identifiers**

If the identifiers are known or computed ahead of time, let's explore an alternative -

```js
const t = popRandom(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])

console.log(t(),t(),t()) // d c a
console.log(t(),t(),t()) // b e f
console.log(t())         // Error: no more values
```

Starting with the input array and `n = keys.length`, random `r` can be any value 0 up to (excluding) `n`. Let's say `r = 3` for the first iteration -

```js
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
                 ^ r = 3
```

`"d"` will be the first return value, then swap `keys[r]` with end of the array `keys[n - 1]`, resulting in -

```js
["a", "b", "c", "f", "e", "d"]
```

In the next iteration `n = 5` so the only valid random elements are `a`, `b`, `c`, `f`, `e` -

```js
["a", "b", "c", "f", "e", "d"]
  ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
                      n = 5
```

Once `n = 0`, there are no more values and alert the caller. Now we implement it -

```js
function popRandom(keys) {
  let n = keys.length
  let r, q
  return () => {
    if (n == 0) throw Error("no more values")
    r = Math.random() * n >> 0;
    q = keys[r]
    keys[r] = keys[n - 1]
    keys[n - 1] = q
    n -= 1
    return q
  }
}

const keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
const t = popRandom(keys)

console.log(t(),t(),t()) // e d a
console.log(t(),t(),t()) // c f b
console.log(keys) // keys are shuffled
console.log(t()) // error no more values
```

**shuffled output**

once `popRandom` has exhausted all possible values, the input keys will be shuffled. See [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for more info.

**immutable keys**

If you don't want to mutate the input keys, simply copy them at input -

```js
const t = popRandom([...myKeys]) // copy 
// t(); t(); t(); ...
```

Comment: Good to see you again.  Nice stuff.  Some comments, though: If by "don't use random" you simply mean don't call `Math.random`, ok.  But it looks like some sort of pseudo-randomized output is part of the requirements.  An LCG (and technically your `createGenerator` is one, I guess) can usually serve this role.  They're only a bit more complex than your code.  Also, I'm curious about "don't use a cache".  I think the LCG approach is cleaner, but a cache can work fine if it's significantly larger than the expected uses.  Finally, a minor nit: why define `n` rather than increment `startingAt`?

Comment: nice to see you. i mean to suggest not using random ids, serial ids do the job and avoid all the obstacles introduced by random ids. to my understanding, LCG guarantees a period but makes no promise about whether particular value will be repeated within that period, so a cache i still needed. the cache can certainly work if you can minimize cache hits (collisions), but minimizing collisions means increasing random space, which also increases the size of individual ids. to me this is complexity without gains, and makes testing harder too.

Comment: it's so funny you catch that `n = startingAt`, i was so conflicted when writing it. to me `startingAt` read as a fixed value and conceptually it shouldn't change. i updated the post but i don't know if it's better. maybe the parameter should be `n`, but then it loses a bit of meaning.. programming is so hard haha

Comment: It does  [take some care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#c_%E2%89%A0_0) to find LCG's with full distribution, but it's not that hard.  I've had use-cases where sequential ids are a bad idea, mostly to avoid users' assumptions about data relationships, but yes, sequential is often enough.  I tend to use LCGs with initial values that themselves are randomized with a seed, which I can hard-code for repeatable testing... Maybe the tricky parameter should be `curr`, `currentVal`, or some such.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your `memoizedRandomKey` function doesn't work is that you're calling the wrong function in the recursive case.  You should be calling the function that it returns, but that function is unnamed, so you'd have to name it.  We could do it like this:

```js
const memoizedRandomKey = (cache = []) => {
  return function getRandom (generateRandomKey) {
    const key = generateRandomKey();
    if (cache.includes(key)) {
      return getRandom(generateRandomKey)
    }
    else {
      cache.push(key)
      return key
    }
  }
}
```

But I think this could be cleaned up a bit.  So I might try something like this:

```js
const generateRandomKey = () => Math .random() .toFixed (2) .slice (2)

const makeRandomizer = (generator, cache = []) => (key = generator ()) =>
  key in cache
    ? makeRandomizer (generator) ()
    : (cache .push (key), key)


const randomId = makeRandomizer (generateRandomKey)

console .log (Array .from ({length: 50}, () => randomId ()))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Still, as others have pointed out, this can run into problems of repeatedly checking as your cache fills up.  An alternative would be to generate all the keys on start, shuffle them, then keep the current index in your closure.  This is easy enough to do when you are limiting yourself to just 100 possibilities, but will get to be a problem for a larger space of potential ids.

For larger cases, you would have to decide what you mean by random, and how much a problem of id collisions would be.  If it's just that they should not seem predictable to casual eyes, then you might try a [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which is easy to calculate, and by starting with a random seed, will look different from run to run.  Remember that while you can make the period as long as you like, but it will be periodic.  If you need something more random, then look at [`Crypto.getRandom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues), but remember that, as unlikely as collisions are, they *can* happen.

Answer (score 0):

With your code you can make 100 keys (0.00 to 0.99). As the cache gets large, the collisions will occur more frequently and you will have a lot of recursive calls - possibly leading to issues like stack overflow. A better solution might be to create all the keys first, then randomly select/remove them as needed.

I work mostly in C++ and C#, so I naturally prefer using classes. (Although it seems JS programmers don't use them too much?). So here's a static class. It creates the 100 keys, then removes/returns them until the list is empty.

```js
class RandomKey {
    static keys = Array.apply(null, Array(100)).map((x, i) => (i / 100).toFixed(2));

    static generate() {
        if (RandomKey.keys.length == 0) {
            throw new Error("No more keys.");
        }
        const index = Math.floor(RandomKey.keys.length * Math.random());
        const selectedKey = RandomKey.keys[index];
        RandomKey.keys.splice(index, 1);
        return selectedKey;
    }
}

// Test
for (let i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
    console.log(RandomKey.generate());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're on the right track. You typically want your `cache` to be part of the closure instead of passing it in as an argument. Maybe something like this.

```js
const generateRandomKey = () => Math.random().toFixed(10)

function makeKeyGenerator() {
  const cache = {};
  return function () {
    let key = generateRandomKey();
    // if the key is in the cache get a new key
    while (key in cache) {
      key = generateRandomKey();
    }
    cache[key] = true;
    console.log(cache);
    return key;
  };
}

const getKey = makeKeyGenerator();

const key = getKey();
```

Note that you're going to run out of keys pretty quickly with `toFixed(2)`. And if that happens, the `while` loop is going to make you have a bad day.